# Recursive Power Function

Tags: c++, math, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive power function without using math.h / pow(), but I keep getting garbage values of `-1.#IND`. I think i'm missing something when I call for a new instance of the power function, but I don't quite understand how to get around it. My full code is fairly short:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double power(double b, int e){
    double x;

    if(e == 0){
        x = b;
    }
    else if(b == 0){
        x = 1;
        e = 0;
    }
    else if(e < 0){
        x = (1 / b) * power(b, ++e);
    }
    else{
        x = b * power(b, --e);
    }

    return x;
}

int main(){
    double num;
    int exp;

    cout << "Please Enter Your Number: ";
    cin >> num;

    cout << "Please Enter The Explonent: ";
    cin >> exp;

    cout << power(num, exp);
    cin >> num;
}
```

Comment: Plus, I think your math is off on the negative power situation. You should be doing `return 1 / (b * power(b, abs(e)--)`

Comment: Some thoughts on your approach: `1.5 ^ 0 == 1`, `1.5 ^ x != 1.5 ^ -x`, `0 ^ x != 1 ^ 0`...

Comment: @Tejs: Uhm.., you probably meant *pre decrement*, rather than *post decrement*

Comment: You should tell us what values you get the error for, from your code it should meet the termination condition for all positive values of `e` so is the error with negative values of `e`?

Comment: I updated my math, but my negative exponent math is a bit off, 2^-3 returns .25 instead of .125, maybe I need setw?

Comment: @Derp: No, you still got the math wrong: `x^0 == 1`, but you return `x`; `0^e == 0`, but you return `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only place you return a value from `power` is where `e==0`.

The other cases compute values, but never return them.

Comment: I can only have 1 return statement per function :S   - i figured when it called the power function after so many times e would be 0 thus returning b

Comment: @Derp No you can have multiple return statements in a function

Comment: @Derp: In that case, you need to deposit a value in the correct variable in every "branch", and at the end return than value.

Comment: @Derp: IF you have a silly rule like that, either use a "returnValue" variable (and return it at the end) or rewrite your if statements to expressions using the ternary operator.

Comment: @Derp If your teacher is disallowing multiple `return`-statements, you should challenge him/her - or consider getting a different teacher.

Comment: @Derp one return per function sounds strange but maybe it is a hint to split it up into more than one function. Oh, and the math is wrong.

Comment: the no return rule is along with a bunch of other rules, like no short if statements, comment everything etc. Very strict standard stuff :(

Answer (score 3):

You forgot returns. Turn on compiler warnings and it will complain.

Answer (score 1):

You might have accepted an answer prematurely. Your code still has problems (2^-3 returns .25) and your code is highly suboptimal. You should be able to compute 1.000001^1000000 with ease (it's very close to *e*), but your algorithm will segfault because it requires a stack depth of about a million. For example, computing a^1024 can be done with only 10 multiplications instead of 1023.